# Jenkins "Jira Issue Updater Plugin" pasrsing error when "Affects Version/s" is not empty

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin

I am facing issues while trying to integrate **JIRA**  with **Jenkins** using **Jira Issue Updater Plugin**

In case of Success(Jira issues not mapped with **Affected version/s** ):

---

### JIRA Update Results Recorder

Updating SA-52         Check_52
Finished: SUCCESS

=====================================

In case of failure ( Jira issues mapped with **Affected version/s**):

---

### JIRA Update Results Recorder

Unable to parse JSON result: {"expand":"names,schema","startAt":0,"maxResults":1000,"total":1,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields","id":"11274","self":"http://benjira01.tally.tallysolutions.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/11274","key":"SA-52","fields":{"summary":"Check _52","versions":[{"self":"http://benjira01.tally.tallysolutions.com:8080/rest/api/2/version/10505","id":"10505","description":"Demo version","name":"1.0","archived":false,"released":false}]}}]}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"expand":"names,schema","startAt":0,"maxResults":1000,"total":1,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields","id":"11274","self":"http://benjira01.tally.tallysolutions.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/11274","key":"SA-52","fields":{"summary":"Check _52","versions":[{"self":"http://benjira01.tally.tallysolutions.com:8080/rest/api/2/version/10505","id":"10505","description":"Demo version","name":"1.0","archived":false,"released":false}]}}]}; **line: 1, column: 320](through reference chain: info.bluefloyd.jira.model.IssueSummaryList["issues"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->info.bluefloyd.jira.model.IssueSummary["fields"]->info.bluefloyd.jira.model.FieldSummary["versions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])Build step 'JIRA Issue Results Updater' marked build as failure** 
Finished: FAILURE

**Note:**  the JSON results when parsed separately,return no error.
The 'other' **Jira plugin** seems to have no problem with the JSON.

Comment: This is problem in the code. I'm a maintainer of the plug in, and I'll have to prepare a new version. The issue is tracked under https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31755